# Rails View Helper Not Inserting HTML into Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-helper

I'm having an issue using a custom helper method in my Rails (3.0) app to output the required html.

I have the following call in my partial view:
_label.html.erb

```
<% display_resource "Diamond", @resource.diamond %>
```

And in the resource_helper.rb file:

```
module ResourceHelper
   def display_resource(display_name, value)
      "<tr><td>#{display_name} </td><td>#{value.to_s}%</td></tr>" if value > 0
   end
end
```

The intended output is:

```
<tr>
  <td>Diamond</td>
  <td>15%</td>
<tr>
```

*granted, without the formatting, and the 15 is arbitrary

If I use the <%= ... %> when performing the method call, it'll output the string correctly, but it won't be html (ie I'll see `"<tr><td>Diamond </td><td>15%</td></tr>"` as opposed to "Diamond 15%")

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Main reason why it isn't printing is because you use `<% %>` instead of `<%= %>`

Comment: If I used <%=...%> it'd output the string, but it would be the actual string (as that's the default behavior of rails now - to prevent XSS and other type of security holes that could arise)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to mark the string returned as "[raw](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw)" and then use <%= %>

```
module ResourceHelper
   def display_resource(display_name, value)
      raw("<tr><td>#{display_name} </td><td>#{value.to_s}%</td></tr>") if value > 0 # string wrapped in raw
   end
end
```

Comment: I just migrated an app to Rails 3, and I'd like to ask: this is a new behavior in how Rails 3 treats HTML Safe strings, correct?

Comment: @Robbie - I believe so - thus why I had this issue (but didn't know how to rectify it.  Thanks for the help Rob!

Comment: Yes, this is the new way rails renders text. By default, all text rendered between <%= .. %> is escaped and you need to use raw() if you have some html that needs to be displayed

Comment: Your smart and I appreciate your help.